# Designing political systems

Tags: discussion, scope

I am trying to design new political system. I have concrete design goals and significant progress on implementation, but met some roadblocks for which I lack knowledge and had no luck with search engines.

I've considered **Worldbuilding SE**, but it does not suit me, because my political system is not supposed to be fictional, nor I am willing to employ any sort of hand-waving or plot armor. Rather, I am basing my design on existing theories and real world implementations.

Would my question fit **Politics SE**?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am afraid not. Brainstorming questions usually drift quickly into subjective territory. When you have new political ideas and would like to discuss them with others, then you might want to do that on a more discussion-oriented website, and not on a QA platform.

But if you need any tangible information about existing political systems and political theory which could be useful in the process of designing a better system, feel free to ask questions to obtain that information.

Comment: If we're not going to allow this, than we really ought to have a political philosophy stack exchange. Maybe if he asked specific, concrete questions?

Comment: @TedWrigley: If you're willing to read answers of the form "Marx said X but Locke said Y," then you can already ask those questions on [Philosophy.SE]. But you do need to phrase it so that it *looks* like Philosophy (i.e. be specific about which theory of political philosophy you're talking about, don't just ask a vague question such as "How is policy X legitimate?").

Comment: @Kevin: I'm over at the Philosophy stack as well. Sometimes Philosophy closes questions down when they think the questions are too close to practical politics. There just doesn't seem to be a sweet-spot on StackExchange for political theory questions (which are my favorite kinds of questions, alas...).